# Switching Tabs In Ribbon UI

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to to switch tabs in a ribbon UI inside the Visual Studio 2010 WPF Designer?
What I mean is this:
[image: WPF UI]

Because a lot of code will go into the next tabs, it's somewhat problematic to execute the application and take note of the necessary complications. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do this in the designer, but you can use a workaround.

In the XAML, find the Ribbon control, and add the `SelectedIndex` attribute.

For example, in order to see the first tab, you can set it to `0`:

```
<ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="TheRibbon" SelectedIndex="0">
```

And if you want to see the second tab, you can set it to `1`:

```
<ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="TheRibbon" SelectedIndex="1">
```

Whenever you are working on a tab, change the SelectedIndex attribute so you can see that tab in the designer.